# Jquery UI : date picker. How to set date in date picker by $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I can't find how I can set $_GET variables to set manually the date in the date picker.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

( example : http://www.something.com/?day=21&month=2&year=2010 )

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the gup function in this [link](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) to read the get parameters. Then call the setDate method (error handling omitted):

```
$(function() {

  $("#Datepicker").datepicker();
  var year = gup("year");
  var day = gup("day");
  var month = gup("month");

  $("#Datepicker").datepicker("setDate", month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

});
```

Comment: I really think that only by completing the input the datepicker is auto set.

Comment: thank you :) :) is gup secured ? i mean do we have to do any htmlspecialchars() on the variables ?

Comment: This is a client-side solution. You should test that year, day and month are actually integers using isNaN method, before building the date string. You can also achieve the same thing in PHP, as other users have suggested. To do so you must also generate your javascript code with PHP - you can't use an external script file.

Answer (score 2):

Simple :)

set minimum date if you want for datepicker:

```
<?php
    $today = mktime(0,0,0,$_GET['month'],$_GET['day'],$_GET['year']);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisday = new Date('<?=(date('Y/m/d', $today);?>');
    $("#YOUR_INPUT").datepicker({minDate: thisday, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
</script>
```

or set automatically from GET variables:

```
<input type="text" name="YOUR_INPUT" id="YOUR_INPUT" value="<?=$_GET['day'];?>/<?=$_GET['month'];?>/<?=$_GET['year'];?>">
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $day = $_GET['day'];
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $date = "'".$day."/".$month."/".$year."'";
?>

<script>
    $.datePicker("setDate", <?php echo $date; ?>);
</script>
```