# How to set DATE in second date-picker on selection of DATE from first date-picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm trying to set a date for `date-picker` on selecting date from first `date-picker`, and want to show an alert message if user selected another date. I'm not able to do that.

**Here is my code:**

```
$('#ELEdatepicker1').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      endDate: new Date(),
      todayHighlight: true,
    }).change(function(){
      getELEdifference($(this),$('#ELEdatepicker2'));
    });
    $('#ELEdatepicker2').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: new Date(),
      todayHighlight: true,
    }).change(function(){
      getELEdifference($('#ELEdatepicker1'),$(this));
      alert('Are you sure ?');
    });

  function getELEdifference($this1,$this2)
  {
    if($this1.datepicker("getDate") != null && $this2.datepicker("getDate") != null)
    {
      var ELEcertDiff= $this1.datepicker("getDate") - $this2.datepicker("getDate");    
      var result = ELEcertDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1;
      //$("#ELEcertDiff").text(result);
      document.getElementById("ELEcertDiff").value = result;
    }
  }
```

How can I show a date (suppose one year latter) in second date-picker ? And if user select before or after one year, it will show alert message on date selection.

***UPDATE:***
Is it possible to pass a parameter to set a difference for second date picker?
For Ex.
[image]
In above picture If I select a date from Issue Date-picker and from duration drop-down list box select a value (Ex. 3), then in Expiry Date-picker shows date after 3 years from selected date.

***I've referred some questions:***

[Jquery UI : date picker. How to set date in date picker by $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874344/jquery-ui-date-picker-how-to-set-date-in-date-picker-by-get)

[Define start date of second date picker from first date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101656/define-start-date-of-second-date-picker-from-first-date-picker)

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery. Any kind of help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz add and check this code:

```
$('#ELEdatepicker1').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        var day = d.getDate();
         var month = d.getMonth();
         var year = d.getFullYear() + 1;
        var newdate = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
        $( "#ELEdatepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newdate );
         $('.highlight a', $(this).next()).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});

$('#ELEdatepicker2').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $("#ELEdatepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        $('.highlight a', $(this).next()).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});
```

Comment: In your answer, it will not give output if we select previous date from current date.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this answer**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ELEdatepicker1">
<input type="text" id="ELEdatepicker2">
<!-- <input type="text" id="ELEcertDiff"> -->
<script>
$('#ELEdatepicker1').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        var year = d.getFullYear() + 1;
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        $( "#ELEdatepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newdate );
         $('.highlight a', $(this).next()).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});

$('#ELEdatepicker2').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $("#ELEdatepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        $('.highlight a', $(this).next()).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It shows date one month before and that one is not highlighted ? How can it be highlighted ?

Comment: If I change date format to dd-mm-yy, it gives me wrong output

Comment: I change this dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd' to dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy', then it give me output in mm-dd-yy format.

Comment: i have added code for highlight and date format in the same answer check it

Comment: Let me know if it's not working or please verify answer if it's working :)

Comment: Please check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ganeshaher/ztn5mmna/  it gives wrong output

Comment: Its not highlighted date from second date-picker

Comment: it's because of dd/mm/yy format i m working on it will update you asap

Comment: Is it possible to give a parameter to change date (year) range like 1, 3, 5, 10 etc ?

Comment: Like what, will you help me out ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164590/discussion-between-ganesh-aher-and-priyank).